# Grep for a pattern

Tags: html, shell

I have an HTML file with the following code

```
<html>
  <body>
    Test #1 '<%aaa(x,y)%>'
    Test #2 '<%bbb(p)%>'
    Test #3 '<%pqr(z)%>'
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me with the regex for a command (grep or awk) which displays the output as follows:

```
'<%aaa(x,y)%>'
'<%bbb(p)%>'
'<%pqr(z)%>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `-o` option for grep is what you want:

`grep -o "'.*'" filename`

Comment: Glenn Thank you for your answer that was a perfect solution what I am looking for.

Comment: Note that the `-o` option is only found in GNU `grep`; it is not supported elsewhere.

Comment: Should be okay for the time being thank you so much I appreciate your help on this

Answer (score 1):

I think that `sed` is a better choice than `awk`, but it is not completely clear cut.

```
sed -n '/ *Test #[0-9]* */s///p' <<!
<html>
  <body>
    Test #1 '<%aaa(x,y)%>'
    Test #2 '<%bbb(p)%>'
    Test #3 '<%pqr(z)%>'
  </body>
</html>
!
```

You can't use `grep`; it returns lines that match a pattern, but doesn't normally edit those lines.

You could use `awk`:

```
awk '/Test #[0-9]+/ { print $3 }'
```

The pattern matches the test lines and prints the third field.  It works because there are no spaces after the test number third field.  If there could be spaces there, then the `sed` script is easier; it already handles them, whereas the `awk` script would have to be modified to handle them properly.

---

Judging from the comments, the desired output is the material between '`<%`' and '`%>`'.  So, we use `sed`, as before:

```
sed -n '/.*\(<%.*%>\).*/s//\1/p'
```

On lines which match 'anything-`<%`-anything-`%>`-anything', replace the whole line with the part between '`<%`' and '`%>`' (including the markers) and print the result.  Note that if there are multiple patterns on the line which match, only the last will be printed.  (The question and comments do not cover what to do in that case, so this is acceptable.  The alternatives are tough and best handled in Perl or perhaps Python.)

If the single quotes on the lines must be preserved, then you can use either of these - I'd use the first with the double quotes surrounding the regex, but they both work and are equivalent.  OTOH, if there were expressions involving `$` signs or back-ticks in the regex, the single-quotes are better; there are no metacharacters within a single-quoted string at the shell level.

```
sed -n "/.*\('<%.*%>'\).*/s//\1/p"
sed -n '/.*\('\''<%.*%>'\''\).*/s//\1/p'
```

The sequence `'\''` is how you embed a single quote into a single-quoted string in a shell script.  The first quote terminates the current string; the backslash-quote generates a single quote, and the last quote starts a new single-quoted string.

Comment: Jonathan thank you for the answer. I am looking for a generic regex. Eg. I want to search for pattern '<%*%>' where * can be anything enclosed between '<% and %>' and display the value as '<%aaa(x,y)%>

Comment: @Veerendra: what does 'generic regex' mean?  What are you seeking to match?  Do you mean you want `"s/.*\('[^']*'\).*/\1/"` because it looks more regex-like?  Be my guest.  But what's in the answer is simple and sufficient for the sample data you gave.  If you have other requirements, you'll have to give them in the question.

Comment: @Jonathan I don't have static content like "Test #" so I cannot search for the pattern "Test #" and print the third argument. I have an awk script which prints the content enclosed between '<' and '>' Eg: awk '{ if ( match($0, /<[^>]*>([^<]+)/, tmp) ) print tmp[1]; }' sample.html I am looking for something similar so that it prints all the '<%aaa(x,y)%>' values in a file

Comment: @Veerendra: so your question didn't make it clear what you are looking for.  What about the single quotes?  They're shown as required in the question, but your comment implies that they're not really wanted after all.  Will your lines contain only one set of material enclosed in angle brackets, or could there be several sets on a line?  Nested sets on a line?  Your first comment implies that you're after material between '`<%`' and '`%>`'.  Anyway, please note that if you ask imprecise questions, you will get imprecise answers.

Comment: @Jonathan I am so sorry if my question was not precise enough. I can improve it over a period of time and this is my first question in the forums. I need to display the quotes output will be exactly the same as in my question and the content enclosed in the angular braces will always be in a single line as '<%getFunc(a,b)%>'

Comment: for file in `find . -name '*.html'`;
do
  echo $file >> obj.log 
  sed -n /'<%get.*>'/p $file | cut -d'%' -f2 >> obj.log
done

This worked for me

Comment: @Veerendra: Your comments are self-contradictory, sadly. In one you say that the single quotes are a required part of the output; in the next you say that chopping out the single quote, the angle bracket and the percent symbol gave you the required result (the `cut -d'%' -f2` command will only give you the `aaa(x,y)` part of the lines). It is impossible for anyone to help you reliably when you change your mind completely as you go through the comments. Also, you need to learn how to adapt given answers to your context. I'll update my answer to capture single quotes too.

Comment: I am glad to receive your help on this. The solution in my previous comment is partial which is complete with Glenns solution. End of the day from this post I have saved lot of time in searching for a pattern in many files.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -P "^Test" 1.htm |awk '{print $3}'
```